# Github Pages site not detecting index.html

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I created a GitHub pages repository. For some reason when I name it
`https://[username].github.io`, it doesn't work, but it works when I name it `https://[username].github.io/index.html`.

Why?

Comment: did you enable it in the settings of that repository ?

Comment: What do you mean? I am able to access it if I give index.html as a suffix right. Is there any setting on github to do that?

Comment: Some how it randomly started working. The url without the appended index.html. Maybe it just needed time for the settings to take effect maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I name it"? What is "it"?

Comment: The issue resolves by adding `baseurl: /` property to `_config.yml`

Comment: What solved it for me: 1) adding the .nojekyll comment (see other posts below) 2) adding `publishDir: docs` in the config.yaml. Then rebuilding the website - this will populate a docs folder with the html & making sure that github pages build on the docs folder.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It got fixed automatically. I just had to wait for a while for the settings to take effect.

Comment: how long did you have to wait?

Comment: @zabop My case, 2min.

Comment: I waited over 30 minutes and nothing happened. It worked on the next day though.

Comment: Took about an hour for me. I'm wondering if they also forgot to fix this for the default branch which is now 'main' instead of 'master'. (Their doc still tells you to push to master, although 'main' is created by default)

Comment: My case, 1 minute.

Comment: My case was cca 5 minutes. They should add a warning stating that it might take some time.

Comment: The browser caches the 404 response. Make sure to disable caching, or retry with a unique query string in the URL.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling, it's not about the browser cache. It's that GH itself caches the response for a min or 2 or 3 and that **seriously sucks** if you are using it as a live IDE.

Answer (score 58):

Pushing a second commit fixed this for me.

Seeing other answers where changes fix this, my guess is that you need to trigger a few of deployments to get it to work.

Every push will trigger a new deployment. You can track deployments at *https://github.com/username/username.github.io/deployments*.

Comment: Push again works for me. seems like problem with some cache

Comment: Pushing another commit also fixed it for me. If it is a cache, it's gotta be something on github's end as even with a hard refresh that should clear caches (`Shift+ctrl+R`) the page without the `index.html` was still 404-ing for me.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2021 in case anyone was wondering. It also happens if you push a commit that deletes your index.html and then push another commit to put it back.

Comment: I just re-run my build workflow and it got fixed.

Comment: Same here! Pushing second commit fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: the deployment tracking thing gives me a 404. I think this has been moved into the actions tab for the repo

Answer (score 33):

If you don't use Jekyll, the workaround is to place a file named .nojekyll in the root directory.

Comment: I'm using Hugo to generate my site, and this worked for me!  Thanks

Comment: @el2e10, does this reduce the wait time from 1 min to 10ms?

Answer (score 15):

I also encountered the same problem today (05/28/2020). Suppose that you have done everything right (instructions in https://pages.github.com/), you should have a repo named `username.github.io` and `index.html` set up.

What worked for me was that I chose a Jekyll theme. First, go to `Settings` of the repo. In `GitHub Pages` section, look for `Theme Chooser` then click on `Choose a Theme`. It will redirect you to a GitHub page that has multiple themes that you can choose from. Choose a theme that you like then click `Select Theme`. After doing these steps, I refreshed my `username.github.io` and the page worked correctly.

Comment: This is one of the reason, without choosing the theme it won't allow access with username.github.io

Answer (score 14):

My index.html had the following DOCTYPE setting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Changing it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: My `index.html` didn't specify `DOCTYPE`, this fixed it for me.

Comment: I had `<!doctype html>` by mistake. Changing it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 14):

### Faced this today (Oct-06-2019)

I double-checked every setting, all of them, didn't fix issue for me unless I changed some content in my index.html file. I also added some files to the repo to make it "alive" but in vain.

So, In my case, I opened up my index.html right in the browser, clicked on edit and added a single word, commit to master branch, refreshed and it took less than 5 seconds and it was up again.

### P.S. I tried pretty much all solutions given anywhere nothing else worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. in my case i added a n extra empty line inside index.html , saved, commited then pushed .. all became fine.

Comment: same for me, just removed an empty line at the top and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me and as soon as I did another commit the issue resolved itself. I just added a space to the index.html file in my dist folder, committed and pushed that change to my gh-pages branch and BAM! Now I can access username.github.io/repository/index.html by just going to username.github.io/repository.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same problem. If you try the link found in the designated repo > Settings > GitHub Pages after an hour after posting all your code, the GitHub page will work.

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem. I had to create random change to my html, go through the git add/commit/push process. That fixed it for me! Now I can access to my page without having to add .html at the end of the url.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using Jekyll, delete the `_config.yml` file from the repository. This fixed the issue for me.

You may also try to push the local repository again.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late to the party but here is how I fixed it for myself today.

1. Go to settings for your repository: You can find Settings tab in your repo page.
2. Scroll down to **GitHub Pages** section on the settings page.
3. In the panel, you will have a **Source** info that states : 'Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the ***gh-pages branch***'.
4. However, in my cases, all code was in *master* branch. So I selected the branch from dropdown as master and in merely a minute, it was published successfully.

Comment: While this wasn't my issue, I can imagine that many people would be caught off-guard by this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for the private repository. My Git project contained index.html in root but the page did not display under `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>` path.

The solution for either way (public repository or not) is in enabling GitHub pages in project repository settings under 'GitHub pages'.

However, be aware that enabling pages under private repository make the .html files public.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on deploying automatically a [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) page from the `gh-pages` branch with [Github Actions](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/actions_sandbox/websites-using-pkgdown-bookdown-and-blogdown.html#deploy-bookdown):

When I tried to access the url proposed by Github in the GitHub Pages section of the repository settings
`https://<username>.github.io/<reponame>/`

I got a **Error404: Page not found** response.

However, manually adding "index.html" at the end of the url displayed the page.
`https://<username>.github.io/<reponame>/index.html`

Adding manually a **CNAME file** with the following content to the `gh-pages` branch solved the issue permanently:

```
 https://<username>.github.io/<reponame>/index.html
```

It's more a workaround though...

**EDIT:**

Adding a `CMAKE` file solved the problem only temporarily as it was removed upon invoking the gh actions workflow.
Either:

**i)** change gh-actions workflow to create the `CMAKE` file at the end (still a workaround...)

or how I could solve it in the specific case of using [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/):

**ii)** in the YAML header of the index.Rmd file, I added

```
url: "https://<username>.github.io/<reponame>/"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more subtle problem which causes this issue.
If you are using image files with huge sizes in the index.html, this problem occurs.
Reducing the size of the images being loaded solved this problem for me.

Comment: But it still happens even if you have no images and your content is just `foo`

Answer (score 0):

In Settings>Github Pages, make sure that the branch selected there is the same as the one you are working with. I had the same problem and the branch was master instead of main so I changed it and it is fixed now.