# My github pages is not loading index.html as a default

Tags: html, github, github-pages

My problem is simply when I go to `username.github.io` it takes me to another page in my repo rather than `index.html` however, when I go to `https://username.github.io/index.html` it works correctly. I would rather have `username.github.io` point directly to `index.html`.

Note: My problem is NOT like the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710488/how-can-i-change-my-github-pages-default-index-html-location)
My problem is also NOT like the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html) as "waiting" doesn't fix it, nor do any of the other solutions given

Edit: It is consistent, rather than going to `index.html` it takes me to a page where I'm hosting a game I made, which also is in a whole other directory and is not even titled `index.html`.

Comment: "it takes me to another page in my repo " — What other page? Is it consistent? Is it random?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github Pages site not detecting index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html)

Comment: It is consistent, it takes me to a page where I'm hosting a game I made. I'll update my question.

Comment: @emix I've updated my question to show why my problem is not like [Github Pages site not detecting index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html)

Comment: @WyattNulton, the proposed duplicate contains _several_ answers. Try all of them, not just the accepted one.

Comment: @Chris I've updated my question to show why my problem is not like [Github Pages site not detecting index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html)

Comment: Did you go to the *username.github.io* repository and check Setting>GitHub Pages section?

Comment: Somebody had to wait at least a day. If it does not resolve contact Github instead.