# 404 File not found with github pages

Tags: html, visual-studio, github, github-pages

I just purchased a domain from godaddy and plan to create a site using github pages.

When I try to go on my domain I get a 404 file not found (looking for index.html file) error. But if I go to my domain and put /index at the end of the file like :[www.mydomainname.com/index](http://www.mydomainname.com/index) it brings me to my index file, is there a way to have the github pages route it to my domain without the /index? Below I have attached the error I'm receiving, my github repo and my github pages config. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

[image: 404 not found]

[image: /index]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check if this helping you or not..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Pages site not detecting index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362628/github-pages-site-not-detecting-index-html)